# ¿Como puedo agregar mas input a mi codigo? sin que me afecte lo que se logro?

Tags: input

Primero quiero explicarles que hace mi codigo: al hacer click solo el input type checkbox ejecuta la funcion myfuncion y me cambia el id por una class para el div, y al final si uno refresca la página o sale de ella, el localStorage recuerda el estado de el checkbox y se ejecuta

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    .mystyle {
     width: 100%;
     padding: 25px;
     background-color: coral;
     color: white;
     font-size: 25px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input id="id-01" name="myFunction" type="checkbox" onchange="myFunction()"><div id="myDIV">This 
            is a DIV element.</div>


   <script> 

    checkbox = document.getElementById('id-01')
     checkbox.checked = eval(window.localStorage.getItem(checkbox.id))

    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function(){
    window.localStorage.setItem(checkbox.id, checkbox.checked)
    })

   </script>

   <script>

             function myFunction() {
            var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");

                 if (element.classList) { 
                element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
               } else {
              var classes = element.className.split(" ");
              var i = classes.indexOf("mystyle");

           if (i >= 0) 
           classes.splice(i, 1);
            else 
                  classes.push("mystyle");
                     element.className = classes.join(" "); 
                   } 
                  }
                </script>

        <script>

           var ele = document.getElementsByName('myFunction'); var i = ele.length; for (var j = 0; j 
         < i; j++) {if (ele[j].checked) {myFunction();} else {}}
       </script>


        </body>
       </html>
```

Mi problema? solo puedo hacerlo con un solo input checkbox, y necesito que realice lo mismo que con un input pero con 5. muchas gracias por su tiempo

Answer (score 0):

No sé mucho de Javascript pero se me ocurre esto, creo que solo faltaría en la funcion `MyFuntion` recibir según la selección, pero no se como hacerlo, actualmente escribí `var element = document.getElementById("myDIV-"+i);` pero no funciona:

```
<script>
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    document.body.innerHTML = "<input id=id-"+i" name=myFunction type=checkbox onchange=myFunction()><div id=myDIV-"+i">This is a DIV element "+i".</div>"
    }
</script>


<script> 

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        checkbox = document.getElementById('id-'+i)
         checkbox.checked = eval(window.localStorage.getItem(checkbox.id))

        checkbox.addEventListener('change', function(){
        window.localStorage.setItem(checkbox.id, checkbox.checked)
        })
    }

 </script>

 <script>

         function myFunction() {
        var element = document.getElementById("myDIV-"+i);

             if (element.classList) { 
            element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
           } else {
          var classes = element.className.split(" ");
          var i = classes.indexOf("mystyle");

       if (i >= 0) 
       classes.splice(i, 1);
        else 
              classes.push("mystyle");
                 element.className = classes.join(" "); 
               } 
              }
            </script>

    <script>

       var ele = document.getElementsByName('myFunction'); var i = ele.length; for (var j = 0; j 
     < i; j++) {if (ele[j].checked) {myFunction();} else {}}
   </script>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por darle de tu tiempo a mi problema, pero no me resulto :( cuidate mucho ;)

Comment: voya tratar de ver como ayudarte, realmente nosé mucho de Javascript